# Error al crear Snapshot Testing

Tags: reactjs

componente

```
if (loading) {
  return <Loading additionalclass="general__loading" />;
}

return (
  <div>
    <nav className="social__icons">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={ROUTES.ANTI_SLAVERY_STATEMENT}>
            {stringsActions.showString(strings.anti_slavery_statement)}
          </a>
        </li>

</nav>
</div>
```

snapshot test

```
  it('snapshot test', () => {
    const loading = false;
    const tree = renderer.create(<FooterMenu loading={loading} />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Al lanzar el test me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {undefined}). d.
        in a (created by Footer)
        in li (created by Footer)
        in ul (created by Footer)
        in nav (created by Footer)
        in div (created by Footer)
        in Footer
```

el stringsActions.showString me trae las cadenas llamando al api y eso es lo que falla segun veo pero no se como hacer que me funcione.

Agradecería que alguien me arrojara algo de luz, ya que soy nuevo en esto de los test :)

Comment: Hola, podrías mostrar qué te devuelve `stringsActions.showString(strings.anti_slavery_statement)` ?

Comment: devuelve strings que vienen de la base de datos, en ese caso devuelve anti slavery statement

Comment: Strings? Debería devolver solo uno, comprueba no esté llegando una lista de strings

Comment: ya lo solucione con jest.fn de la funcion showString